# Why is my MySQL data not displaying to html template?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have been trying to display data from MySQL db but nothing is working. Here is the code:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
 if request.method == "POST":
    food = request.form['food']
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    data = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM recipies WHERE title = %s",[food])
    if data > 0 :
       results = cur.fetchall()
       return render_template('results.html',results=results)
```

and the html

```
% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for result in results %}
        <table>
                <td>{{ result }}</td>
        </table>

{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

When i run it,it gives an error "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."
I don't know what to do.

Comment: do you have an else to the if. Also, i guess that the way you are checking if data is returned is incorrect.

Comment: I tried adding a else but the result is the  same.

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes to your function:

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        food = request.form['food']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM recipies WHERE title = %s",[food])
        results = []
        if not cur.rowcount:
            print "No results found"
        else:
            results = cur.fetchall()
        return render_template('results.html',results=results)
```

Comment: I made the changes but there is no improvement.